# Is there a way to run some code just before creating a Debug/Release build in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, localization

So the requirement is, I am working on a project that needs to create a localized website for each language. We already have a build in English. The thought is, we will create a Datasource(resources) that will have mappings for each language for whole project. We will also have a configuration file that will tell us like language(locale), metrics used in that Locale etc. When we create a Debug/Release build, we need to run a program that will capture the configurations and create a build for those configurations.

Note that the original build should remain unchanged as that will be used to create builds for as many languages we can.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to run multiple builds using build scripts. Your options are [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) and MSBuild.

In the build script you need to create separate packages for different languages that you support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, the [`Pre` and `Post` build events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165412.aspx) are intended for scenarios such as you describe

You can access them from the Properties tab of your project:

[image]

Comment: But, wouldn't that change my original build itself? I want my original build to remain in English and create a separate builds for each language.

Comment: The idea is to abstract all your locale specific data (string tables, images, etc) into [separate Resource Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

After spending two days, I have a solution and thanks to @Sunil and @StuartLC for their input. The simplest solution for my situation is, I don't even need to create separate builds for each language. I can simply add the below line in web.config under system.web with culture information I need. The build will be ready for that culture.

```
//For English (United States)
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
//For German (Germany)
<globalization uiCulture="de-DE" culture="de-DE"/>
```

Since I will be using my own Database Resource Provider, my web.cofig line would look something like below.

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="MyResourceProviderName.MyResourceProviderFactory" uiCulture="de-DE" culture="de-DE"/>
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="MyResourceProviderName.MyResourceProviderFactory" uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
```

I hope this will help someone in future.